# Issue Loading MapView Anotations from a plist array - Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2, mapkit

I'm working on an iPhone application that displays a list of galleries on a Map.  The list of galleries comes from a plist which is downloaded from the web. The location coordinates are loading into the map correctly as well as the title and subtitle for each of the locations.

I am also able to load an image for the annotation view image from the plist.

The issue I'm having is that both the annotation view image and a detail view page load the information of the last location in the plist array rather than loading the information that corresponds to the correct location information.

I believe that the problem has to do with this integer:
for(int i=0; i < [galleries count]; i++)

but I'm honestly not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code:

**MapAnnotation.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>

@interface MapAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>{

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
NSString *title;
NSString *subTitle;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end
```

**MapAnnotation.m**

```
#import "MapAnnotation.h"

@implementation MapAnnotation
@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle;

@end
```

**MapViewViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>{

NSMutableArray *galleries;
MKMapView *_MapView;
MKAnnotationView *Ann;

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *_MapView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKAnnotationView *Ann;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *addressArray;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *galleries;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imageUrl;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData *imagedata;


-(IBAction)getlocation;

- (void)loadAnnotations;


@end
```

**MapViewViewController.m**

```
#import "MapViewViewController.h"
#import "MapAnnotation.h"
#import "MoredetailViewController.h"


@implementation MapViewViewController
@synthesize _MapView, Ann;
@synthesize galleries, addressArray;
@synthesize imagedata, imageUrl;


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[galleries removeAllObjects];

addressArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.jimirobinson.com/plist/MapInformation.plist"]];    

galleries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:addressArray];

[self loadAnnotations]; 

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = 39.952133;
region.center.longitude = -75.144264;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.001;

[_MapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}


-(IBAction)getlocation {
_MapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}


- (void)loadAnnotations {

CLLocationCoordinate2D pinCoordinates;

for (int i = 0; i < [galleries count]; i++)
{

    MapAnnotation *myAnnotations = [[MapAnnotation alloc] init];

    pinCoordinates.latitude = [[[galleries objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];
    pinCoordinates.longitude = [[[galleries objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue];
    [myAnnotations setTitle:[[galleries objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"annotation_title"]];
    [myAnnotations setSubtitle:[[galleries objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"annotation_subtitle"]];

    imageUrl = [[galleries objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"map_pin_image_url"];
    imagedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];

    [myAnnotations setCoordinate:pinCoordinates];
    [_MapView addAnnotation:myAnnotations];

}

                    }


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView :(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"AddrAnnot"];

annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"AddrAnnot"];

    if (_MapView.userLocation == annotation)
            {
            return nil;
            }

annotationView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imagedata];          
annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
[annotationView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[annotationView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView =  [[UIImageView  alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flag1.png"]];


[_MapView addAnnotation:annotation];
return annotationView;

NSLog(@"%s: annotationView=%@", __func__, annotationView);

}




- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{

MoredetailViewController *moredetail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TextPage"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:moredetail animated:YES];


for(int i=0; i < [galleries count]; i++)        
{
    moredetail.MoredetailTitle.text = [[galleries objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"annotation_title"];  

    moredetail.MoredetailDescription.text = [[galleries objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"annotation_subtitle"];
    NSLog(@"%d", i);


    NSString *image = [[galleries objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"map_pin_image_url"];  
    NSData *dataz = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image]];
    moredetail.detailImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataz];
} 


NSLog(@"I've been tapped");

}



- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views { 

NSLog(@"%s: galleries=%@", __func__, galleries);

}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}


@end
```

**MapInformation.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>Gallery One</string>
    <key>annotation_title</key>
    <string>Gallery One Title</string>
    <key>annotation_subtitle</key>
    <string>Gallery One Subtitle</string>
    <key>map_pin_image_url</key>
    <string>http://www.jimirobinson.com/plist/flag1.png</string>
    <key>latitude</key>
    <real>39.952827</real>
    <key>longitude</key>
    <real>-75.145203</real>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>Gallery Two</string>
    <key>annotation_title</key>
    <string>Gallery Two Title</string>
    <key>annotation_subtitle</key>
    <string>Gallery Two Subtitle</string>
    <key>map_pin_image_url</key>
    <string>http://www.jimirobinson.com/plist/flag2.png</string>
    <key>latitude</key>
    <real>39.952184</real>
    <key>longitude</key>
    <real>-75.145368</real>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>Gallery Three</string>
    <key>annotation_title</key>
    <string>Gallery Three Title</string>
    <key>annotation_subtitle</key>
    <string>Gallery Three Subtitle</string>
    <key>map_pin_image_url</key>
    <string>http://www.jimirobinson.com/plist/flag3.png</string>
    <key>latitude</key>
    <real>39.951135</real>
    <key>longitude</key>
    <real>-75.143368</real>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid to say but this code needs lots of work in order to work as you expect.

Firstly, `imagedata` is an instance variable, and you are setting it to be the image data of the last annotation (in `loadAnnotations`).  `viewForAnnotation` then uses `imagedata` for the image, so it will always be set to the image for the last annotation.

Secondly, in `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` you are iterating over all the galleries, and setting properties on the `moredetail` view controller, so that the view controller will always show detail for the last gallery.

I suggest that you add more properties to your `MapAnnotation` class, such as imageUrl. You can then set this property when creating the annotations. In `viewForAnnotation` you can then do this:

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapAnnotation class]]) 
{
      MapAnnotation *mapAnnotation = (MapAnnotation *)annotation;
      annotationView.image = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[mapAnnotation imageURL]];
```

And in the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method you can do this:

```
MapAnnotation *mapAnnotationPressed = (MapAnnotation *)view.annotation;
moredetail.MoredetailTitle.text = [mapAnnotationPressed title];
```

I hope this gives you some idea of how to get your code working.

Comment: Andy, Thank You!  I was able to get it working based on your suggestions.